Share a post on linkedin using salesforce LWC component
I want to add a feature in my Salesforce LMS project allowing user to sharing their earned badges (PNG) on LinkedIn as a Post.
What I have done so far is:
const linkedInShareUrl = `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticlemini=true&url=${encodeURIComponent("https://my_custom_URL")}&title=${encodeURIComponent("Earn Your Badge!")}&summary=${encodeURIComponent("Check out this amazing course and earn badges!")}&source=${encodeURIComponent("https://redge-dev-ed.develop.my.site.com")}`;

Using this above code, nothing is working except url parameter.
How we can pass other information on LinkedIn so that it'll pick return url, image and custom text?
